# Siteurl - craft.app.request.absoluteUrl() output missing "www"

Tags: url, siteurl, env

How can I add "www" to the output of {{ craft.app.request.absoluteUrl }}?

In my .env file I have

```
DEFAULT_SITE_URL="https://www.mysite.com"
```

but

```
{{ craft.app.request.absoluteUrl() }}
```

only outputs https://mysite.com without the "www".  How can I fix that?

Comment: Craft will listen on whatever vhost you give it. Is your web server setup to redirect non-www to www?

Answer (score 2):

*Maybe there's a better solution but:*

`{{ craft.app.request.absoluteUrl()|replace({'https://': "https://www."}) }}`

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/replace.html

Comment: That works nicely, thank you!